# How to exclude file types in filesearch of Notepad++?

Tags: filter, notepad++

I want to search my soucecode directory for specific texts. When i do so, i want to exclude DLL-Files.

Is there a way to exclude a file instead of listing all filetypes to search?

[image]

This example would only search in DLL-Files. I'd like to insert a "NOT" in this filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Notepad++ version `7.8.5` 64-bit supports this notation for filters:

- filters: `* !*.dll`

All files but `*.dll`

Comment: Interesting fact: semicolon as seperator does not work for excludes: `*;!*.dll`  does not work. `*.dll;*.txt` works (finds dll and txt files)